# Checkout a project from Project Online using REST calls

Tags: rest, project, sharepoint-online

First, I did verify that have the permissions to checkout a project via the web interface. Now, I'm trying to replicate that checkout using REST calls and I cannot get past 'HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN'.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = WinHttpClients.createDefault();
// url = http://<site>/ProjectServer/Projects(guid'xxxx')/checkOut
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(baseURL + URL);
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("X-RequestDigest", getDigest());
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(""));
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
response.close();
httpclient.close();
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or missing in the call stack?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 means the server can reach the resource and process the request but refuses to take any further action due to the permissions. Please see the below explanation.

For Eg: If Support, Admin are two Roles defined in the project and only Admin has permission to create a new resource.

```
@RolesAllowed("Admin")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response createProject(Project p)
{
    ..
}
```

And if the request is being made by the user "Support", the serve can authenticate the user "Support" but will refuse with 403 as the user does not have "Admin" privileges.

Try to add the authentication header with the legitimate user and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but as I said above, I "should" already have the appropriate permissions - according to the admin, I have 'Full Control'. Using WinHttpClients automatically adds an NLTMAuthentication header to the request. I have asked the admin to try the request himself, but I haven't heard back.

Comment: The issue has suddenly resolved itself with no action on my part. The code above works as advertised.

Comment: I know this isn't a DIRECT answer to your quandary, but I hope it may help. I've posted a full example of a COMMS package (Java code) to read/write data into Project Web App (SharePoint based) @ [link to technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0f9c56e2-8be3-46bb-aa6d-a4b29ef8bc73/project-online-rest-api-to-add-a-task-to-project?forum=projectonline) Hopefully, you'll find something useful there. I know it works (using UID/PWD, not a BEARER token - which is also a significant difference, but shouldn't make a difference) because it's used in a crontab every day.